# Book or article for Transformation matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra

If $T:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^m$ is a real linear map, then there is a unique matrix (called Transformation matrix) $M(T)\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ such that for each $v=(v_1,...,v_n)\in\mathbb{R}$,
\begin{equation*}
T(v)=M(T)v^T.
\end{equation*}

I need a book that includes the proposition as following:

Let $S,T:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^m$ and $U,V:\mathbb{R}^m\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^\ell$ be real linear maps. Then
\begin{equation*}
M[(T+S)(V+U)]=[M(T)+M(S)][M(V)+M(U)].
\end{equation*}

Comment: Why need a book for this specifically? This could be an exercise in a typical linear algebra book. Here's a proof: $M[(T + S)(V + U)] = M(T + S) M(V + U) = (M(T) + M(S))(M(V) + M(U))$. In the first step I used the fact that if $A: \mathbb R^m \to \mathbb R^\ell$ and $B: \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^m$ then $M(AB) = M(A) M(B)$. (This is proved in most linear algebra books.) In the second I used the fact that $M(T + S) = M(T) + M(S)$ (which should also be proved in most linear algebra books).

Comment: You are right. Thank you.

Comment: I am sorry for that. I also need more propositions. As $M(T)^{-1}=M(T^{-1})$, $M(T)^{t}=M(T^{t})$ and so on. Can you recommend a linear algebra book? I can prove them, but I do not want to write the proofs of them.

Comment: So I need a book to solve all problems after quoting.

Comment: Why don't you want to write the proofs of them? What's your situation?

Comment: I write a paper to use them including generalized inverse. I am not quite sure the people in our approach know them well. But I could not write the proof in the paper, they are too long.

Comment: I think it'd be ok to just use these facts without proof. Or perhaps state them without proof.  These are very basic facts, we don't have to provide a reference for all the basic math that we do in a math paper. For example if you compute the derivative in a math paper we don't need to cite a calculus book.

Comment: Thank you very much.